# View Destructors in C++

Tags: c++, oop, destructor

I have a small piece of code that shows the order the constructors and destructors are called in an inheritance. However I am not able to view the destructors because they are only called at the end of the program. Is there a way to stop the console before it closes? I'm using MVS 2013. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout << "Constructor A" << endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "Destructor A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        cout << "Constructor B" << endl;
    }
    ~B()
    {
        cout << "Destructor B" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    C()
    {
        cout << "Constructor C" << endl;
    }
    ~C()
    {
        cout << "Destructor C" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public C
{
public:
    D()
    {
        cout << "Constructor D" << endl;
    }
    ~D()
    {
        cout << "Destructor D" << endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A r;
    B z;
    C t;
    D q;

    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse, etc? You can place a breakpoint at any line you wish to see during execution.

Answer (score 2):

Run your program manually from the command line, rather than having it started from within Visual Studio.

In order to do that, open a command-line window (cmd.exe), navigate to the directory of your Visual Studio project and go either to the `Release` or `Debug` subdirectory (if you are using standard Visual Studio settings). There you'll find an .exe file to run.

Answer (score 1):

Write the main the following way

```
int main()
{
    {
        A r;
        B z;
        C t;
        D q;
    } 

    system("Pause");
}
```

In MS VS you could use key combination Ctrl + F5 to run the program without any changes of it.

Comment: `system("pause")` just...no.

Comment: `system("pause")` is OS dependent! There's no OS specified in the OP.

Comment: What if I want to use the program e.g. in a batch file?

Comment: @Christian Hackl The author of the topic uses his program as he wants. I am sure he is not interesting what somebody here wants.

Comment: @Christian Hackl He wrote his simple program only to see the order of calling destructors of the classes.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: He may be interested in doing things the right way in the long run, though. And even if he's not interested, other beginners stumbling upon this question may be. It's not like `system("pause")` is the only way in the world to view output written to stdout right before a program finishes.

Comment: The author himself used `system("Pause")`, Vlad only adjusted the scope so his console messages are written **before** `system("Pause")`, no need to downvote Vlad.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CTRL + F5 command to start your program without debugger. Console windows shouldn't close after program termination.